# Не загружается сайт с включенными devTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Захожу на эту страницу, хочу просмотреть запросы, которые отправляет сайт

```
https://www.bet365.ee/#/IP/B1
```

Открываю Chrome devTools, захожу во вкладку Network, перезагружаю сайт и он уходит в бесконечную загрузку. Как только закрываю devTools, он сразу начинает загружать полноценную страницу.

И в связи с этим несколько вопросов:

1. Как сайт понимает, когда открыты инструменты разработчика?
2. Можно ли это как-то обойти?
3. Какие есть еще способы просмотреть запросы, не используя devTools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скачал firefox и все заработало

Answer (score 1):

1. 

Это мой скрипт, можете взять

```js
(function {
const devtools = {
      'try': false,
      'isOpen': false,
      'enabled': true
    };
    const runDetect = () => {
      if(!devtools.enabled) return;
      if(devtools.try) return;
      devtools["try"] = true;
      // document.location.href = "/detected"; - на другую страницу (лучший вариант для браузерной игры)
      // document.body.innerHTML = "" // пустая страница
    };
    let data = {
      'message': {
        get() {
          devtools.isOpen = true;
          runDetect();
        }
      },
      'toString': {
        value() {
          if (new Error().stack.includes("toString@")) {
            devtools.isOpen = true;
            runDetect();
          }
        }
      }
    };
    console.log(Object.defineProperties(new Error, data));
})();
```

Как только откроется консоль, он пытается прочитать Error у которого есть геттер(message > get()) и все, детектив!

2. Можно, только нужно посмотреть какой у сайта антидевтул , потом уже напишем свой скрипт(userscript) tampermonkey